# adding view to ViewFlipper causes java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I want to have a dialog with buttons

whenever i click on a specific button, I want the dialog to "flip" and show another layout. A click on another button will return to the original dialog's view.

I try to use ViewFlipper as follows:

xmls:

**send_feedback_dialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/feedback" />
    </LinearLayout>
...
```

**social_actions_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <ViewFlipper         
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="407dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_card_face"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="407dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onCardClick"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

...
```

code:

```
            final ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) mDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);

            View feedbackview = View.inflate(mContext,
                    R.layout.send_feedback_dialog, viewFlipper);

            // ((ViewGroup)
            // feedbackview.getParent()).removeView(feedbackview);
            // viewFlipper.addView(feedbackview);

            // View socialActions = View.inflate(mContext,
            // R.layout.social_actions_dialog, viewFlipper);

            // ((ViewGroup) socialActions.getParent())
            // .removeView(socialActions);
            // viewFlipper.addView(socialActions);





private void flipDialog(ViewFlipper viewFlipper,
                boolean isSocialActionsShown, AlphaAnimation alphaIn,
                AlphaAnimation alphaOut) {
            if (isSocialActionsShown) {
                isSocialActionsShown = false;

                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(alphaIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(alphaOut);
                // Show the next Screen
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            } else {
                isSocialActionsShown = true;

                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(alphaIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(alphaOut);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        }
```

I used to get `java.lang.StackOverflowError` and then i have commented some rows and now the flip is executed but nothing changes.

how can i make it properly work?

what is the right way to organize the dialog layout in different files?

i have tried to create the dialog in a different file but it requires many things and maybe it's better to use it as an inner class

Comment: Where do you get the error?
Why do you inflating the feedbackView with a parent and then removing it?

Comment: how should i do it then?

Comment: Try to manipulate the View(s) in your ViewFlipper, you must not inflate them every time.
Hte only reson for this is when you want to inflate a diferent Layout.

Comment: but it will never be inflated then

Comment: Your ViewFlipper holds 2 Views(RelativeLayout)?
This Layouts should hold your content to display.
Is that right?
Does the two Layouts should hold a static content(the ViewTypes and their count will not change), or you want change the content(add a new TextView)?
First solution:add all your content to the layouts in your ViewFlipper per xml, retrieve the Views in your code (a TextView or so) and manipulate them.
Second solution: add only two "container" Layouts (RelativeLayout, or FrameLayout) in your ViewFlipper in xml, in code inflate content from other xml and add it to the "containers"